# Wrong pose estimate when using Charuco on image with higher resolution

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, aruco, transformation-matrix

I'm working on a project where a high quality pose estimate is needed. I am therefore trying to get this pose estimate using OpenCV charuco board. Previously I have been using a Aruco board of size 2x2, but the pose estimate was not sufficient.
I have made the charuco estimate work using a realSense D415 camera with resolution 640x480. However, when I change the resolution to 1280x720 the coordinate system which I draw on the board, starts jumping around completely random.

The code for estimating the charuco board is here:

```
void ReconstructionSystem::detect_charuco_markers(cv::Mat& image, cv::Matx33f& matrix, cv::Vec<float, 5>& coef, int& centerPix_x, int& centerPix_y, cv::Vec3d& rotation, bool& arucoFound)
{
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_50);
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::CharucoBoard> board = cv::aruco::CharucoBoard::create(3, 3, 0.04f, 0.02f, dictionary);
    cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::DetectorParameters> params = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters::create();
    //params->cornerRefinementMethod = cv::aruco::CORNER_REFINE_NONE;

    std::vector<int> markerIds;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> markerCorners;
    cv::Mat copyImage;
    image.copyTo(copyImage);
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(copyImage, gray, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(gray, board->getDictionary(), markerCorners, markerIds, params);
    // if at least one marker detected
    if (markerIds.size() > 3) {
        cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(image, markerCorners, markerIds);
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> charucoCorners;
        std::vector<int> charucoIds;
        cv::aruco::interpolateCornersCharuco(markerCorners, markerIds, gray, board, charucoCorners, charucoIds, matrix, coef);
        // if at least one charuco corner detected
        if (charucoIds.size() > 3) {
            cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0);
            cv::aruco::drawDetectedCornersCharuco(image, charucoCorners, charucoIds, color);
            cv::Vec3d rvec, tvec;
            bool valid = cv::aruco::estimatePoseCharucoBoard(charucoCorners, charucoIds, board, matrix, coef, rvec, tvec);
            // if charuco pose is valid
            if (valid){
                cv::drawFrameAxes(image, matrix, coef, rvec, tvec, 0.1f);
                arucoFound = true;
            }
            else
            {
                arucoFound = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            arucoFound = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        arucoFound = false;
    }
    board = NULL;
    dictionary = NULL;
    copyImage.release();
    gray.release();
}
```

The function above is called within this while loop:

```
//Variables for transformation matrices
    int centerPix_x = 0, centerPix_y = 0;
    cv::Vec3d rotationVec;
    cv::Matx33f rotation;
    bool arucoWasFound = false;
    std::vector<float> final_x, final_y, final_z;
    std::vector<float> rotation_x, rotation_y, rotation_z;
    cv::Matx33f matrix = get_cameraMatrix(path);
    cv::Vec<float, 5> coef = get_distCoeffs(path);


    const auto window_name = "Validation image";
    cv::namedWindow(window_name, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    // TODO Also add here that if we have iterated through X frames and not found Aruco, exit with failure
    while (cv::waitKey(1) < 0 && cv::getWindowProperty(window_name, cv::WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE) >= 0 && counter < 60) {
        rs2::frame f = sensorPtr->color_data.wait_for_frame();
        // Query frame size (width and height)
        const int w = f.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_width();
        const int h = f.as<rs2::video_frame>().get_height();
        cv::Mat image(cv::Size(w, h), CV_8UC3, (void*)f.get_data(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
        cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
        //detect_aruco_markers(image, matrix, coef, centerPix_x, centerPix_y, rotationVec, arucoWasFound);
        detect_charuco_markers(image, matrix, coef, centerPix_x, centerPix_y, rotationVec, arucoWasFound);

        if (arucoWasFound)
        {
            rs2::depth_frame depth = sensorPtr->depth_data.wait_for_frame();
            rs2_intrinsics intrinsic = rs2::video_stream_profile(depth.get_profile()).get_intrinsics();
            float pixel_distance_in_meters = depth.get_distance(centerPix_x, centerPix_y);
            float InputPixelAsFloat[2];
            InputPixelAsFloat[0] = centerPix_x;
            InputPixelAsFloat[1] = centerPix_y;
            float finalDepthPoint[3];
            rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(finalDepthPoint, &intrinsic, InputPixelAsFloat, pixel_distance_in_meters);

            // Postion //
            final_x.push_back(finalDepthPoint[0]);
            final_y.push_back(finalDepthPoint[1]);
            final_z.push_back(finalDepthPoint[2]);

            // Rotation //
            rotation_x.push_back(rotationVec[0]);
            rotation_y.push_back(rotationVec[1]);
            rotation_z.push_back(rotationVec[2]);

            counter++;
        }
        cv::imshow(window_name, image);
    }
    cv::destroyWindow(window_name);
```

Furthermore, here is an image of the detection using resolution of 1270x720.

[image: Image when using 1280x720 resolution]

And here is an image of the detection with resolution 640x480.
[image]

If anybody knows why this is happening please let me know :D

Comment: How do you set your camera matrix? Camera matrices for different resolutions will differ and it seems that you use camera matrix for 640x480 to process images with higher resolution.

Comment: Hi @PiotrSiekański. You were completely right. I had taken the images in resolution 1280x720, but in my calibration code I gave the wrong image size to the cv function ' cv::calibrateCamera'. I have now fixed it, and it seems to work very well. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out the problem was that the calibration of the cameras had been made with a wrong resolution, in my case 640x480 instead of 1280x720. Below is the code I used to calculate the calibration matrix and coefficients. The two values that were wrong were: cv::Size frameSize(_imageWidth, _imageWidth);

```
void ReconstructionSystem::camera_calibration()
{
    std::string folder_501("\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\501_images\\*.png");
    std::string folder_309("\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\309_images\\*.png");
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    {
        std::vector<cv::String> filenames;
        std::string currentCam;
        if (x == 0) currentCam = folder_501;
        if (x == 1) currentCam = folder_309;

        cv::glob(currentCam, filenames, false);
        for each (std::string var in filenames)
        {
            printf("file: %s\n", var.c_str());
        }
        cv::Size patterSize(9, 6);
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> q(filenames.size());

        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> Q;

        int checkerboard[2] = { 10, 7 };   //size of checkerboard
        int square_size = 27;           //2.7 cm == 27mm

        std::vector<cv::Point3f> objp;
        for (int i = 1; i < checkerboard[1]; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < checkerboard[0]; j++) {
                objp.push_back(cv::Point3f(j * square_size, i * square_size, 0));
            }
        }
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> imgPoint;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        for (auto const& f : filenames) {
            std::cout << std::string(f) << std::endl;

            cv::Mat img = cv::imread(filenames[i]);
            cv::Mat gray;

            cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            bool patternFound = cv::findChessboardCorners(gray, patterSize, q[i], cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv::CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
            if (patternFound) {
                cv::cornerSubPix(gray, q[i], cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1), cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::EPS + cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001));
                Q.push_back(objp);
            }
            // Display
            cv::drawChessboardCorners(img, patterSize, q[i], patternFound);
            cv::imshow("chessboard detection", img);
            cv::waitKey(0);
            i++;
        }


        cv::Matx33f K(cv::Matx33f::eye());
        cv::Vec<float, 5> k(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
        std::vector<double> stdIntrinsics, stdExtrinsics, perViewErrors;
        int flags = cv::CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO + cv::CALIB_FIX_K3 + cv::CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST + cv::CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT;
        cv::Size frameSize(_imageWidth, _imageWidth);

        std::cout << "calibrating..." << std::endl;

        float error = cv::calibrateCamera(Q, q, frameSize, K, k, rvecs, tvecs, flags); 
        std::cout << "reprojection error = " << error << "\nK = \n" << K << "\nk=\n" << k << std::endl;

        if (x == 0) {
            std::string path_mat = "\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\104122061501\\calibration_Mat_new.yml";
            std::string path_coe = ("\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\104122061501\\calibration_coef_new.yml");
            saveData_mat(path_mat, K);
            saveData_coef(path_coe, k);
        }
        if (x == 1) {
            std::string path_mat = "\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\102122061309\\calibration_Mat_new.yml";
            std::string path_coe = ("\\Users\\Mikke\\Desktop\\Calibration\\102122061309\\calibration_coef_new.yml");
            saveData_mat(path_mat, K);
            saveData_coef(path_coe, k);
        }
    }
}
```